# Is it possible to show railway-infrastructure in lower zoom-levels?

Tags: openmaptiles

I want to replace the base-layer in an existing project with openMapTiles from a own server. When I've tested the Docker-Image, I saw that the railway-infrastructure disappears at lower zoom-levels.
Is it possible to include Data tagged with #transportation class: rail in lower zoom-levels?
Thanks in advance!